# Spark overwrite parquet files on aws s3 raise URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet, pyspark

I am using Spark to write and read parquet files on AWS S3. I have parquet files which stored in

```
's3a://mybucket/file_name.parquet/company_name=company_name/record_day=2019-01-01 00:00:00'
```

partitioned by *'company_name'* and *'record_day'*

I want to write basic pipeline to update my parquet files on regularly basis by 'record_day'. To do this, i am gonna use overwrite mode:

```
df.write.mode('overwrite').parquet(s3a://mybucket/file_name.parquet/company_name='company_name'/record_day='2019-01-01 00:00:00')
```

But am getting unexpected error **'java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: key=2019-01-01 00:00:00'**.

I spent several hours searching for the problem but found no solution(. For some tests, I replaced the *'overwrite'* parameter with *'append'*, and everything works fine. I also made a simple dataframe and overwrite mode also works fine on it. I know that i can solve my problem in a different way, by deleting and then writing the particular part, but I would like to understand what the cause of the error is?
Spark 2.4.4 Hadoop 2.8.5

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and the my solution was to remove the `:` part in the date.